# What is the correct way to commit clean a workspace before commiting?

Tags: control, ros, catkin, svn, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I work with svn and git and instead of committing my whole catkin workspace with built binaries etc, what is the best way to clean the worskpace before committing it. So that when someone else checks it out they just source devel/setup.bash and catkin_make?

Thx

EDIT: So far just not including the "build" file seems to do the trick - is this the best way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234126/what-is-the-correct-way-to-commit-clean-a-workspace-before-commiting?/) by [kleinash](https://answers.ros.org/users/2345/kleinash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-12**:
Related question: [Using git for version control with catkin (added>>>) and Eclipse](http://answers.ros.org/question/216664).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't do it like this at all.
You should just commit the packages in the `src` folder.

Checking out a workspace including `devel` will not work, as the `setup.sh` (which is sourced by `setup.bash`) contains the global path to the workspace (i.e. /home//...).

Just explain how to set up the workspace properly...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4